# Once i start implementing html styles for my program i always get this error and i cant find where i go wrong: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a calender here where today's `background-color` is yellow. Altough every time I try to add CSS code to make the `background-color` change to yellow, I run into the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file.

I really can't find where I'm going wrong. Code below:

```
<html>
<head><title>Kalender</title></head>
<body>
<h1> Een kalender voor de maand
<?php

$months = array(1 => "Januari", 2 => "Februari", 3 => "Maart", 4 => "April", 5 => "Mei", 6 => "Juni", 7 => "Juli", 8 => "Augustus", 9 => "September", 10 => "October", 11 => "November", 12 => "December");

$date = getdate();
$month = $date['mon'];

$currentMonth = $months[$month];
echo ("$currentMonth");?>.</h1>

<?php


//Eerste dag van de maand: ma,di,wo,do,vr,za,zo.
$month_start = strtotime('first day of this month', time());
//echo date('l', $month_start).'<br/>';

$maandStartDagen = array("Monday" , "Tuesday" , "Wednesday" , "Thursday" , "Friday" , "Saturday" , "Sunday");

$maandDagen = cal_days_in_month (CAL_GREGORIAN , $month , 2017);
//echo ("$maandDagen");

$eersteDagVanMaand = date('l', $month_start);
//echo $eersteDagVanMaand;

$vandaag = date("j");
//echo ("$vandaag");

//$index = 0;
$index = array_search("$eersteDagVanMaand", $maandStartDagen);
//echo ("$index");


//input voor functie kalender.

//aantal lege dagen in de eerste rij voordat de dagen beginnen met tellen.
$maandstart = $index;

$weekRij1 = 0; $weekRij2 = 0; $weekRij3 = 0; $weekRij4 = 0; $weekRij5 = 0; $weekRij6 = 0;

//aantal dagen in de eerste rij waar de dagen beginnen tellen.
$weekRij1 = 7 - $index;         $maandDagen = $maandDagen - $weekRij1;

$weekRij2 = 7;                  $maandDagen = $maandDagen - $weekRij2;

$weekRij3 = 7;                  $maandDagen = $maandDagen - $weekRij3;

$weekRij4 = 7;                  $maandDagen = $maandDagen - $weekRij4;


if($maandDagen == 0){}

elseif($maandDagen <= 7){
    $weekRij5 = $maandDagen;    $maandDagen = $maandDagen - $weekRij5;
}

else{
    $weekRij5 = 7;              $maandDagen = $maandDagen - $weekRij5; 
}


if($maandDagen == 0){}

else{
    $weekRij6 = $maandDagen;    $maandDagen = $maandDagen - $weekRij6;
}


?>



<table>
<tr>
<th>Ma</th>
<th>Di</th>
<th>Wo</th>
<th>Do</th>
<th>Vr</th>
<th>Za</th>
<th>Zo</th>
</tr>

<?php
//voorgeprogrameerde weken in vorige alinea php-code.
//If else statements in for loops om ervoor te zorgen dat $vandaag een gele achtergrond krijgt.
function kalender($maandstart, $weekRij1, $weekRij2, $weekRij3, $weekRij4, $weekRij5, $weekRij6, $vandaag){}

//eerste week
?><tr><?php

//aantal lege dagen voordat het tellen begint van de weekdagen
$teller = 0;
while($teller != $maandstart){
    ?><td></td><?php
    $teller++;
}

//dagen waarvoor er wel de datum van de dag geteld moet worden voor de kalender
$teller = 0;
$dag = 0;
while($teller != $weekRij1){
    $dag++;
    if($dag == $vandaag){?><td style="background-color: yellow;"><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
    else{?><td><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
}?></tr><?php

//weekrij 2 invullen
?><tr><?php
$teller = 0;
while($teller != $weekRij2){
    $dag++;
    if($dag == $vandaag){?><td style="background-color: yellow;"><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
    else{?><td><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
}?></tr><?php

//weekrij 3 invullen
?><tr><?php
$teller = 0;
while($teller != $weekRij3){
    $dag++;
    if($dag == $vandaag){?><td style="background-color: yellow;"><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
    else{?><td><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
}?></tr><?php

//weelrij 4 invullen
?><tr><?php
$teller = 0;
while($teller != $weekRij4){
    $dag++;
    if($dag == $vandaag){?><td style="background-color: yellow;"><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
    else{?><td><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
}?></tr><?php

//weekrij 5 invullen
?><tr><?php
$teller = 0;
while($teller != $weekRij5){
    $dag++;
    if($dag == $vandaag){?><td style="background-color: yellow;"><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
    else{?><td><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
}?></tr><?php

//weekrij 6 invullen
?><tr><?php
$teller = 0;
while($teller != $weekRij6){
    $dag++;
    if($dag == $vandaag){?><td style="background-color: yellow;"><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
    else{?><td><?php echo("$dag"); ?></td><?php}
}?></tr><?php

echo("$maandstart"." $weekRij1"." $vandaag"."<br>");
echo("$weekRij2"."<br>");
echo("$weekRij3"."<br>");
echo("$weekRij4"."<br>");
echo("$weekRij5"."<br>");
echo("$weekRij6"."<br>");

?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many instances where you are writing `<?php}` instead of `<?php }`, you're missing a space between the end of `php` and the bracket.

Fix all culprits and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you man! The code works fine now.

Comment: Glad it worked!
If this answers your question, feel free to accept the answer:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Will do once i can, 2 more mins.

Comment: By the way, next way you encounter a syntax error and the error doesn't say where, copy paste your code here: http://phpcodechecker.com/